# HDF5 and Cmake Issues

Tags: c, xcode, linker-errors, hdf5

I am trying to write to an HDF5 file from Xcode. I am getting this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_H5Fclose", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_H5Fcreate", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_H5LTmake_dataset_float", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_H5check_version", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_H5open", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

which led me to believe that I had not downloaded HDF5 correctly even though I have h5py working in Anaconda. I am attempting to redownload and configure the HDF5 with cmake, but that is a long process. Has anyone successfully gotten HDF5 to work in C in Xcode that could guide me in the right direction?

Comment: How do you configure CMake to use HDF5? The feature `FindHDF5` should help you. The Anaconda environment is independent from the XCode toolchain and does not matter here.